# How to render date field?

Tags: theming, users, datetime

I'm currently trying to customize my registration form with a custome template file.

Everything is going fine except for the date-field where users can set their birthdate (field_geboortedatum in my code).

```
<?php
print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
?>

<?php print drupal_render($form['field_voornaam']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_naam']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_geboortedatum']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['account']['mail']); >

<?php print drupal_render($form['submit']); ?>
```

I'm using the Date module (http://drupal.org/project/date) with Drupal 7.

Ayone any ideas how I can render the datefield corectly? I don't want to render my whole form at once because I want more control over my layout.

Comment: Ok so actually the answer was pretty stupid.
I just had to check "Display on user registration form." in the settings page of the date field.

Comment: In the future, instead of leaving a comment, you should answer your own question and then mark that answer as accepted.  *Drupal Answers* encourages you to answer your own questions when you find the answer; this helps future users who may have the same question that you did.